# How do I set up debugging under my local IIS for an MVC3 app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7.5

My host is having issues getting my MVC3 app to work on their server, so I though I'd check it out myself.  Until now I've been too busy developing under the built in server to worry about IIS, but today I tried my first deployment to the host with no joy.  Then I tried one to my local IIS, with no joy.  Then I tried telling VS to use IIS for debugging, to maybe resolve some local issues, with no joy.

What steps and configuration are required to use local IIS 7.5 to debug an MVC3 application?

**EDIT:**  Going through a browser, after clearing up a permission problem for my Windows user on Temp ASP.NET Files, I now site with a I get a HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden), but the occassional basic auth login dialogue.  Here I have tried a Forms auth user, my normal Windows user, and my Windows admin user, all to no avail.

When I try and debug under VS, I get a 500, internal error.

**THE PLOT THICKENS:**  When I enable directory browsing on the site, I get a proper directory listing for the site root url.  This suggests the the MVC3 routing is not working, but why not?

Comment: You might want to better describe the steps you took and the lack of joy involved. Could be 1000 little things but in principle it should generally just work.

Comment: Can you describe any error messages you're seeing?

Comment: Phew, that's a bit hard because I've been trying many different options, with many different negative results.  I just discovered a permissions problem, so I'll append what happens from now on, into my question in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a directory listing that means there's not a default file set (for IIS6). It usually means the request wasn't routed to IIS to deal with. thing are slightly different with II7 & it's integrated pipeline.

Simon

Comment: To set a default in IIS you have to select a file, and MVC doesn't use physical pages as defaults, but rather uses routes set up in global.asax.

Comment: Default document is just a setting. it looks for files listed in order & returns that if it finds one. otherwise it shows the directory, if directory browsing is enabled. Mine says default.htm, default.asp, index.htm, index.html, iisstart.htm, default.aspx. I don't think this applies to IIS7 & MVC though